# Longest plateau

Tags: java, beginner, array

Problem statement:

> #### Longest plateau
>
> Given an array of integers, compose a program that finds the length and
> location of the longest contiguous sequence of
> equal values where the values of the elements just before and just
> after this sequence are smaller.

This is a naive solution. Teaching myself programming . Please comment on how you would solve the problem and if there are any glaring style issues. How would a professional solution to this program look? Also , if this program were given to you in a programming interview would you write it any differently?

```
public class LargestPlataeu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] value = new int[args.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length; i++){
            value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        //print index 
        for(int i = 0 ; i <args.length;i++){
            System.out.print(i+ " ");
        }
        //print values at index
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0 ; i <args.length;i++){
            System.out.print(value[i]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        int inp_length = value.length;
        int len_big_pt = 0;
        int big_p1=0;
        int big_p2=0;
        //if platuea exists it can start anywhere between 0 and length-3. Can't exist after that
        for(int p1 = 0; p1 < inp_length-3;p1++){
            //Plataue cant start at the first 3 locations
            for(int p2 = p1+3;p2< inp_length;p2++){
                boolean condition1=false;
                boolean condition2=true;
                //value at the end of the plateau can be less or equal to value at the begining .
                if(value[p2]<=value[p1]){
                    condition1 = true;
                    //all middle values equal and higher than 1st value
                    for(int p = p1+2;p <p2;p++){

                        condition2 = true;
                        if((value[p]!=value[p-1]||value[p]<=value[p1])){
                            condition2 = false;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(condition1&&condition2){
                    System.out.println(p1+" "+p2+ "  val[p1] "+ value[p1]+ "  val[p2] "+ value[p2]);
                    System.out.println("plateau");
                    int pt_len = p2 - p1;
                    if(pt_len >= len_big_pt){
                        len_big_pt = pt_len;
                        big_p1 = p1;
                        big_p2 = p2;
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
        if(len_big_pt>0){
            System.out.println("Biggest plateau exists from "+big_p1+" to "+big_p2);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No plateau");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview.SE! Please take the [tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I took the liberty to add the [tag:beginner]-tag to your question. In case that was inappropriate, please do roll the edit back. I additionally added some formatting to the opening text of the question.

Comment: Why do you check if `value[p2]<=value[p1]`? It doesn't matter how the surrounding numbers compare to each other, they just have to be smaller than the middle values. Right now, the code works for `[2,3,3,1]`, but not for `[1,3,3,2]`. Also, you didn't consider the possibility that a plateau may consist of one number only. For example, in`[1,2,1]`, `2` would fulfill the requirements for a plateau.

Comment: @Stingy:Yep thats a bug. Thanks for pointing that out. As for the case of plateau containing one number only, based on this part of the statement "longest contiguous sequence of equal values" , I assumed that there should be a sequence of equal numbers. So the shortest sequence of equal numbers will be of length 2

Answer (score 4):

I fully agree with Timothy's answer that your code doesn't really follow the [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so you should read up on those and get into the habbit of using names that tell exactly what the variable represents at first glance. For example renaming your `inp_length` to `inputLenght` and `len_big_pt` to `lengthBiggestPlateau`.

Now let's look at how to improve your solution to a more "professional" one.

First off, let's start by introducing methods. A good place to start are your comments that state what the lines following the comment are doing.

```
...
//print index
for(int i = 0 ; i <args.length;i++){
    System.out.print(i+ " ");
}
//print values at index
System.out.println();
for(int i = 0 ; i <args.length;i++){
    System.out.print(value[i]+ " ");
}
System.out.println();
...
```

So let's extract these loops into a method that prints out the input array

```
private static void printInput(int[] value) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < value.length;i++){
        System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <value.length;i++){
        System.out.print(value[i]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I'm still not happy with this implementation because an index and it's corresponding value might not be aligned properly. Let's instead construct 2 strings while looping over the values and add padding where needed. I'm also using a StringBuilder while constructing these Strings so that we don't needlessly create new String objects when appending the next value.

```
private static void printInput(int[] values) {
    StringBuilder indecesString = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder valuesString = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length;i++){
        indecesString.append(i).append(" ");
        valuesString.append(values[i]).append(" ");

        while(indecesString.length() < valuesString.length()){
            indecesString.append(" ");
        }
        while(indecesString.length() > valuesString.length()){
            valuesString.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indecesString.toString());
    System.out.println(valuesString.toString());
}
```

Next let's write a method that parses the input arguments into an int array.

```
private static int[] parseInputArray(String[] args) {
    int[] value = new int[args.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length; i++){
        value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Our main program now starts like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = parseInputArray(args);
    printInput(values);
```

This is looking more like readable steps that our program is executing. The next logical step would be "find the largest plateau". Since we just want to print it, let's create a method `printLargestPlateau(values)`. That way, our main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = parseInputArray(args);
    printInput(values);
    printLargestPlateau(values);
}
```

To make it easier for ourselves to test the next refactorings let's also hard code an input array for now. That way we don't need to type in all the numbers each time we execute the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int[] values = parseInputArray(args);
    int[] values = new int[]{2,2,2,1,2,3,3,2,1};
```

Even better would be to write unit tests but that's out of scope for this answer.

As for the actual plateau searching algorithm I think we can do a bit better than how you handled it. Let's loop over each value once and check if it rises/drops/stays the same. Depending on those 3 cases we need to handle it differently:

1. If it rises we can start a new plateau. We keep track of this index.
2. If it drops we first check if a plateau has been started before. If so we check if the current found plateau is the biggest one and store it if applicable. Also reset the tracking so we have to find a start of a plateau again.
3. It stayed the same, so increase the lenght of the current plateau.

It's been a bit tricky to get all the required tracking variables and conditions entirely correct but I found a solution. We have to keep track of the start and length of the largest plateau (up til now) and the current plateau. We also need to check if we had started a plateau already or not. And we need to keep track of the index we're currently checking (as a looping index over all values). This results in the following implementation:

```
public static void printLargestPlateau(int[] values) {
    int biggestStartIndex = -1;
    int biggestLenth = 0;
    int currentIndex = 1;
    int currentPlateauStartIndex = 1;
    int currentLenght = 1;
    boolean plateauStarted = false;
    while (currentIndex < values.length) {
        if(isStartOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)){
            plateauStarted = true;
            currentPlateauStartIndex = currentIndex;
        } else if (isEndOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)) {
            if(plateauStarted && currentLenght > biggestLenth){
                biggestLenth = currentLenght;
                biggestStartIndex = currentPlateauStartIndex;
            }
            plateauStarted = false;
            currentLenght = 1;
        } else {
            currentLenght++;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
    if(biggestStartIndex < 0){
        System.out.println("No plateau");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Biggest plateau starts at index: "+biggestStartIndex +" and has length: "+biggestLenth);
    }
}

private static boolean isStartOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index-1] < values[index];
}

private static boolean isEndOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index - 1] > values[index];
}
```

Notice how I also extracted 2 methods to check if an index is a start or an end of a plateau. This makes the algorithm easier to read than if I had put the actual value check there.

I did change the way the result is printed though. I now print the starting index and the lenght of the plateau like the question asks. I found it a bit confusing the print the index before and after the plateau.

Comment: Nice answer! Except that the solution is still *procedural*... upvoted anyway...

Comment: Thank you , your answer was very insightful . If you were given this problem statement in a programming interview where there is a time crunch would you cut corners like I did here?

Comment: No :) I would write it exactly as I did here. Writing extra methods doesn't slow you down in any way. It just takes a couple extra seconds to type the method signature, but you gain a lot more by keeping the code clear. If it's part of a bigger project where you have more time and have to combine multiple things I would probably work a bit more towards specialised classes. The result would be something between this solution and that of Timothy Truckle.

Comment: Good answer. Just an observation: `currentPlateauStartIndex` can be derived from `currentIndex` and `currentLength`. But storing it in a variable does make the code easier to read. I would replace that while loop with a for loop though, to further improve readability.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: `printLargestPlateau` contains both the plateau-finding algorithm and printing/UI code. I would separate that. Still, +1.

Comment: You are entirely correct @PieterWitvoet which is also what I commented on Timothy's answer. That's the one thing I'm not happy about in this solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing your code!

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers.

#### Naming Conventions

Please
read (and follow) the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

#### Avoid short identifiers

In Java the length of identifier names names is virtually unlimited. There is no penalty in any way for long identifier names. So don't be stingy with letters when choosing names.

## General approach

#### OOP

You present a *procedural* approach.
There is nothing wrong with this except that you do it in *Java*.

Java is an *object oriented* language. So If you want to become a good Java programmer you should start using Objects and (more important) follow *OO principles* as there are:

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

and others. You code shows non of them.

As a reference here is a more OO like approach:

```
interface Plateau extends Comparable<Plateau> {
    Plateau appendNextValue(int nextValue);

    int compareCountTo(int otherConsecutiveValueCount);
}
```

---

```
class RealPlateau implements Plateau {
    private int startIndex;
    private int value;
    private int consecutiveValueCount = 0;  
    public RealPlateau(int startIndex, int value) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Plateau appendNextValue(int nextValue) {
        if (this.value == nextValue) {
            consecutiveValueCount++; // enlarge the current plateau
            return this;
        }
        if (this.value > nextValue) { // found end of a real Plateau
            return new NonPlateau(startIndex + (++consecutiveValueCount), value); // nextValue cannot be start of a plateau.
        }
        // a new plateau might start here, so reset state
        startIndex += ++consecutiveValueCount;
        this.value = nextValue;
        consecutiveValueCount = 0;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Plateau o) {
        return o.compareCountTo(consecutiveValueCount);
    }   
    @Override
    public int compareCountTo(int otherConsecutiveValueCount) {
        return otherConsecutiveValueCount - consecutiveValueCount;
    }   
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RealPlataeu [startIndex=" + startIndex + ", value=" + value + ", consecutiveValueCount="
                + consecutiveValueCount + "]";
    }   
}
```

---

```
class NonPlateau implements Plateau {
    private final int value;
    private int startIndex; 
    public NonPlateau(int startIndex, int value) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Plateau o) {
        return o.compareCountTo(-1); // non plataeus are always shorter
    }   
    @Override
    public Plateau appendNextValue(int nextValue) {
        startIndex++;
        if (this.value < nextValue) // new plateau might start here
            return new RealPlateau(startIndex, nextValue);
        this.value = nextValue;
        return this;
    }   
    @Override
    public int compareCountTo(int otherConsecutiveValueCount) {
        return otherConsecutiveValueCount + 1; // reverse logic
    }   
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NonPlataeu";
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class LargestPlateau {   
        private static final String LONGEST_PLATEAU_IS = "longest Plateau is: %s";
        private static final int SKIP_FIRST_VALUE = 1;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LargestPlateau largestPlateau = new LargestPlateau();
            System.out.println(String.format(LONGEST_PLATEAU_IS, largestPlateau.findLongestPlateauIn(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1 })));
            System.out.println(String.format(LONGEST_PLATEAU_IS, largestPlateau.findLongestPlateauIn(new int[] {  1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4})));
            System.out.println(String.format(LONGEST_PLATEAU_IS, largestPlateau.findLongestPlateauIn(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4 })));
        }
    }

    public Plateau findLongestPlateauIn(int[] valueList) {
        Set<Plateau> plateaus = findAllPlateaus(valueList);
        return selectLongestPlateau(plateaus);
    }

    private Plateau selectLongestPlateau(Set<Plateau> plataeus) {
        Plateau longestPlataeu = plataeus.stream().max((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2)).get();
        return longestPlataeu;
    }

    private Set<Plateau> findAllPlateaus(int[] valueList) {
        Set<Plateau> plateaus = new HashSet<>();
        Plateau currentPlateau = new RealPlateau(0, valueList[0]);
        plateaus.add(currentPlateau);
        for (int i = SKIP_FIRST_VALUE; i < valueList.length; i++) {
            Plateau nextPlateau = currentPlateau.appendNextValue(valueList[i]);
            if (currentPlateau != nextPlateau) {
                plateaus.add(nextPlateau);
                currentPlateau = nextPlateau;
            }
        }
        return plateaus;
    }
}
```

---

> ---
>
> Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the design decisions that you made to write the code the way you did esp. in context of OO programming practices you listed above. As a beginner I was only able to identify information hiding / encapsulation. – I just want to code

Here are some reasonings:

### Separation of Concerns / Single Responsibility

I split up the requirement into different tasks:

- converting input into `int[]` array (omitted)
- identifying plateaus
- finding the longest
- output of the result

Then I decomposed the  *identifying plateaus* task as follows:

- detect beginning of plateau

  When looking at the rules a plateau must be preceded by a lower value. In that case the current value may be the first value of a plateau or part of the raising slope.
- detect end  of plateau

  If the current Value is lower than the previous then the Plateau ended. 
  (I intentionally did *not* prevent "single value" plateaus since the result is the shall be the longest which will always rule out the "peeks".)

This gave me the idea of having two "analyzer" classes with same *interface* but different *behavior*

### "Tell! Don't ask!"

In my code there is no method with boolean return value nor is any `if` using a value outside the current object.

Also my code does not have any *getter* method.

Especially the change between `RealPlateau` and `NoPlateau` is *not* done by the `LargestPlateau` class.

Comment: This started of as a great answer. Then ended with a greatly overdesigned example which doesn't really help a beginner to see the benefits of OO design. So I'll neither up nor downvote it and we'll see if others do like it.

Comment: @Imus what is your suggestion to improve the example? In which way is it "overdesigned"?

Comment: The question to me sounds like it should be a relatively simple for loop checking for a value rise - stay equal- value drop and check the length of that. That could still fit inside 1 maybe 2 methods, instead of an interface and 2 classes with multiple methods each :)

Comment: I'll try my own implementation first and see if it actually is that simple. If it's not I'll upvote your answer. Otherwise I'll post my own aproach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the design decisions that you made to write the code the way you did esp. in context of OO programming practices you listed above. As a beginner I was only able to identify information hiding / encapsulation.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I gave my own implementation but I think a better solution would be somewhere between that and yours. I'm mostly unhappy that my method doesn't return the plateau (I didn't want to work around returning 2 parameters: the index and length). So I upvoted your solution for pointing out the important stuff and showing an alternative (despit that being somewat overdesigned, just not as much as I initially thought).

Comment: @Ijustwanttocode Single responsibility as well. Although it might be easier to reason about "single reason for change" instead. The only reason one of the Plateau classes will change is if we change the definition of a plateau. Separation of concerns (and KISS) follow by looking at what a method does exactly, and then looking at it's name. Each method does one thing at a certain level of abstraction. And by looking at the name you can expect exactly what follows in it's implementation.

Comment: `If you want to become a good Java programmer` - a good programmer uses the right tools for the job. A single method, and perhaps a few helper methods and maybe a small return-value class should be enough to implement this algorithm. All this extra code doesn't come for free: since the core algorithm is spread across multiple classes it's more difficult to understand and to maintain.

Comment: There's a good idea here though: a method that returns all plateaus (`findAllPlateaus`). That's a nice and flexible building block - if someone wants to find the longest plateau, chances are they want to find other plateaus as well, and that method makes it very easy to react to such requirements changes.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet *"a good programmer uses the right tools for the job."* including choosing a *procedural language* (and not Java) when solving a *procedural problem*. But the OP decided for Java and consequently should create an OO aproach.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: but OO does not mean 'overengineered', and using Java does not imply that your code has to be overly complicated, as Imus' answer demonstrates. I'm just saying that all this extra code comes at a cost, so it should provide some actual value to justify its existence.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I totally agree with you when talking about *real live projects*. But the OPs code obviously is for training purpose and IMHO there are slightly different goals...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: the OP's question was: 'how would you write this in a professional or interview setting'. Training isn't only about learning how to use a tool, it's also about learning when to use which tool (or combination of tools).

Comment: The OP decided for Java and consequently *should create an approach that works in Java*. I would think that the point of programming in Java is the same as for any other programming language: To declare one's intention in a way that the compiler can understand it, and not to use objects for the sake of using objects because Java is called object-oriented. `Math.max(int, int)` is a […]

Comment: […] straightforward translation from "find the larger of two integers" to Java; you don't need an object for it (unless you're [this guy](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html)). I don't see any merit in solving a "procedural problem" with an "OO approach" just because the language is primarily object-oriented, even though a "procedural approach" could be implemented in an uncomplicated manner.